# Mac and PC variation in line-height/vertical align of text elements

Tags: cross-platform, css

Am currently styling a site and testing across all browsers, Mac and PC.

All singular text elements (`input`s, `span`s, `li` etc.) have a padding above the text of a couple of pixels in PC browsers, however the text sits flush at the top of the elements in Mac Browsers.

I am using a CSS reset and have tried altering line-heights and display modes of various elements with no luck. Is this a common problem and is there a fix?

Comment: can you post your CSS please?

Comment: I was thinking you need a CSS reset before I saw that you had implemented one. Are you using meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset? Unfortunately, that can only go so far, depending on how precise you need the design to be across however many browsers. You'll eventually have to end up using at least some browser-specific hacks css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks. I used to use hacks, now I simply avoid at all costs. It really depends on the project. If you can give me the link to the site/page/example in question I can take a crack at it for you (avoiding hacks).